# Update on any child table's row is locking entire parent table in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle18c

I have a parent table PT having below columns 
PT_ID, 
PT1_ID, 
PT2_ID,
PT_COMMENT

Another child table CT is there having below columns

CT_ID,
PT_ID,
PT1_ID,
PT2_ID,
CT_COMMENT

There are rows in CT table where foreign key columns are having null values (means no value)

If we are updating the CT_COMMENT in CT table for more than 320 rows and at the same time in **another seesion** we are trying to update one parent table comment in PT_COMMENT column which is not happening until child records update is not getting completed.

Here same Parent table PT_ID row is not getting updated in child table CT, Though Parent Table is getting stuck.

Can anyone help me out to figure it out the reason for locking?

Thank in advance

Comment: Check you have indexes on your foreign key columns. My guess is that you haven't. See [this AskTOM answer](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:292016138754) for more info.

Comment: Yes, one of my indexes was not created for all foreign key constraint columns. I recreated with appropriate columns and now it's working. Thank you @Boneist

Answer (score 0):

The index was not appropriate, hence the parent table was getting locked.
After the recreation of an index, now it is working.